# Issues with Timers in C#

Tags: c#, timer

So I have a timer that changes the image in a picture box every time it runs. I have a random number generated and depending on what number it is it will stop on that image. So initially the timer works the first time without fail, it will stop on the correct image with no problems. the second time it goes through it will glitch and be wrong, the third time it will stop after 1 sec or so and the forth time it freezes. What i don't understand is how can the timer work perfectly the first time and is stopped (which i thought would reset the timer) then the second time a push a button to activate the timer again and it goes messed up?.

here is some of my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WheelOfFortune
{
public partial class f : Form
{
    private static Random r = new Random();
    private static int spin = 0;
    private static int t1 = 0;
    private static int t2 = 0;
    private static int t3 = 0;
    private static int rn = 0;
    private static System.Timers.Timer st = new System.Timers.Timer();

    public f()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Wheel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Spin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        if (spin == 0) {
            t1 = 0;
            t2 = 0;
            t3 = 0;
            spin = 1;
            rn = r.Next(1, 53);
            Console.WriteLine("" + rn);
            st.Stop();
            st.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            st.Interval = 15;
            st.Start();
        }

    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        t1 = t1 + 6;
        if (t1 == 1)
        {
            Wheel.Image = Properties.Resources.Wheel_Test_0001;
        }
        else if (t1 == 2)
        {
            Wheel.Image = Properties.Resources.Wheel_Test_0002;
        }
        else if (t1 == 3)
        {
            Wheel.Image = Properties.Resources.Wheel_Test_0003;
        }
        else if (t1 == 4)
        {
            Wheel.Image = Properties.Resources.Wheel_Test_0004;
        }
        else if (t1 == 5)
        {
            Wheel.Image = Properties.Resources.Wheel_Test_0005;
        }
        else if (t1 == 6)
        {
            Wheel.Image = Properties.Resources.Wheel_Test_0006;
        }
        else if (t1 == 7)
        {
            Wheel.Image = Properties.Resources.Wheel_Test_0007;
        }
        else if (t1 == 8)
        {
            Wheel.Image = Properties.Resources.Wheel_Test_0008;
        }
        else if (t1 == 9)
        {
            Wheel.Image = Properties.Resources.Wheel_Test_0009;
        }
        else if (t1 == 10)
        {
            Wheel.Image = Properties.Resources.Wheel_Test_0010;
        }
        else if (t1 == 11)
        {
            Wheel.Image = Properties.Resources.Wheel_Test_0011;
        }
        else if (t1 == 12)
        {
            Wheel.Image = Properties.Resources.Wheel_Test_0012;

            if(rn == 2)
            {
                t2 = t2 + 1;
                if (t2 == 1)
                {
                    t3 = t3 + 1;
                    if (t3 == 4)
                    {
                        spin = 0;
                        t3 = 0;
                        t1 = 0;

                        st.Stop();
                    }
                    t2 = 0;
                }

            }
        }
```

the code is rather repeated after this as there are 624 images to go through as is skipping 6 at a time at the start then will gradually slow down. (I have not implemented the slow down part yet).

I just can't seem to see a reason why the timer doesn't reset and do the same again, am i missing something?

Comment: When you restart the timer, you also add a second time the event handler. This could contribute to what you see.

Comment: You should probably switch to `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. See the first "Tip" box on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx).

Comment: are you saying that the timer is some how doubling up?

Comment: You keep on adding a handler and never removing it.  After 10 clicks, you've got 10 handlers going off when the timer elapses.  That would cause all sorts of issues, on top of other design flaws that you have over there.

Comment: yeah sorry i'm very new to C# timers are so much easier in java, how do i go about removing the handler?

Comment: You don't need to keep re-assigning the same event handler. If your code will always use the same function when the timer expires then just assign it once either in the designer or in the constructor after InitializeComponent

Comment: Also, in your code above, the statements to load images when t1 is between 1 and 6 will never fire, you are always adding 6 to t1 and then you reset it to 0, so the value will always be 6 on the first stop event.

Comment: I Know I have only just started coding this, 6 will become an integer that slowly decreases so the images slow down, man i feel so stupid now well at least that was an easy fix thanks guys.

Comment: You've also got the timer popping every 15 milliseconds, which is about the best timer resolution you are going to get on Windows.  I don't think there is any way your Elapsed method can keep up with that.  Just setting the image and having WinForms render it will take longer than that.

Comment: yea well originally i wanted to use all 624 images but the timer couldn't make it spin fast enough to i decided to skip frames which also ended up to be my solution to slowing it down as well so kinda worked out thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you know that you can use a resource manager to reduce your code by a lot.

```
ResourceManager _resourceManager= Resources.ResourceManager;
...
```

**Timer event**

```
 string _imageName=SomeLeftPaddFunction(4,"0",t1);//function to always pad to 4 0's
 Wheel.Image = (Bitmap)_resourceManager.GetObject("Wheel_Test_"+_imageName);
```

**Caching images**

```
public class ImageCacheItem
{
    int Index{get;set;}
    Bitmap Image{get;set;}
} 
...
List<ImageCacheItem> _imageCache=new List<ImageCacheItem>();
....
```

**Timer event**

```
Wheel.Image=_imageCache.Where(p=>p.Index==t1).FirstOrDefault();
if(Wheel.Image==null)
{ 
    string _imageName=SomeLeftPaddFunction(4,"0",t1);//function to always pad to 4 0's
    _imageCache.Add(new {Index=t1,Image=(Bitmap)_resourceManager.GetObject("Wheel_Test_"+_imageName);
    Wheel.Image=_imageCache.Where(p=>p.Index==t1).First();

}
```